# How to configure mongodb in servicestack

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, servicestack

I'm trying to use MongoDB as the persistence back-end for ServiceStack's Authentication module, so I've added the following node in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myDb" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/mydb?safe=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And here below is my `Configure` method:

```
public class MyAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public MyAppHost () : base("My Web Services", typeof(MyService).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {
            new BasicAuthProvider()
        }));
        Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

        var connectionString = ... // how do I retrieve "mongodb://localhost"?
        var dbName = ...           // how do I retrieve "mydb"?
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
        var db = server.GetDatabase(dbName);

        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(new MongoDBAuthRepository(db, true));
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve the connection string and database name from `web.config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to access your App or Web.Config appSettings is:

```
var appSettings = new AppSettings();
var connStr = appSettings.GetString("myDbConnectionString");
```

That's if you keep all your config settings in the `<appSettings/>` tag.

To access a connection string kept in the `<connectionStrings>`, you could use ConfigUtils, e.g:

```
var connStr = ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("MyDb");
```